# Calculate the total number of pages that will print from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, math, printing, datagridview

I'm trying to calculate the total number of pages that will print from a DataGridView.
A new page will print once the total column length is greater than the total printed area.
For each new page it will always print column 0 so that columns width will need added to get the correct calculations.

Here is what I have so far that always seems to come up short with page numbers

```
//dgv = the DataGridView
//RectangleF printable_area = MarginBounds

float total_width = 0;

//grab the width of each column
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    total_width += dgv.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Size.Width;
}
//divide the total width by the printable area's width
int pages = (int)Math.Ceiling(total_width / (printable_area.Size.Width));

//add to the total width the size of column 0 * the number of pages
total_width += dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Size.Width * pages;

//return the total number of pages that will be printed
return (int)Math.Ceiling(total_width / (printable_area.Size.Width));
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you would actually be having more pages than necessary, since you're including the first page's Column[0] twice in the calculation (the variable `i` should start at 1 in my opinion), but then I realised that this calculation

```
int pages = (int)Math.Ceiling(total_width / (printable_area.Size.Width));
```

will assume columns can be spread over pages.

Lets say you have 4 columns, each 100 width in size. Now lets say your printable area is of width 150. Ignoring the requirement to print the first column on each page, this would give you 3 pages, because 400/150 is 2.67, rounding up to 3. However, what you would actually want, is 4 pages, because two columns can never fit on one page, and the extra "gap" of width 50 is unusable per page.

This is assuming you do not want to print half or part of a column on each page. If this was your intent, then I cannot see anything further wrong with your code

Comment: I switched to PageBounds and just adjusted where needed and it is now working correctly. I stepped through the above code and wrote it down on paper and the calculations were correct after making the adjustment so Column[0] was not added to page 1 twice.